# 2 dimensional arrays for loops statements java programming

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to write a for statement that sums up the rows and columns of a 2 dimensional array one at a time, and determines if all the sums are the same. I have done the following, and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
 public static int isMagic(int mat[][])
    {
        int row = mat.length;
        int col = mat[0].length;
        int sum = row + col;
        if(row == col)
        {
            System.out.println("The matrix is a magic square.");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("The matrix is not a magic square.");
        }
        return sum;
        for(int sumR = 0; sumR < mat.length; sumR++)
        {
            int total = 0;
            for(int sumC = 0; sumC < mat[sumR].length; sumC++)
            {
                total += mat[sumR][sumC];
                if(sumR == 34 && sumC == 34)
                {
                    System.out.println("The sum of all rows and columns is 34.");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("The matrix is not a magic square.");
                }
            }
            return total;
        }
    }
```

example of the matrix.

1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9

Comment: But this is totally wrong sumR ans sumC are just iterators, and the only way that they can be equal to 34 is if the number of rows and columns of the matriz is bigger than 34.

Comment: Please paste an example of the matriz and what should be the output

Comment: do you get any error? if you do post up your stack trace? if you do not , post up your expected output with what you get as your output right now plz?

Comment: Are you wanting the sum of row1 = sum of col1, sum of row2 = sum of row2, etc...?  Or are you wanting the sum of all rows = sum of all cols?

Comment: I get that the for statement is an unreachable statement.

Comment: It doesn't really have to equal to 34. it should proceed to sum rows and columns one at a time and determine if all the sums are the same. I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You always return the the variable sum (row + col), it never reaches the loops.
Just remove the first return statement and it should work.

Answer (score -1):

I don't recommend that you use your sum variable as your index. Maybe do something like this:

```
    for(int r = 0; r < mat.length; r++){
      for(int c = 0; c < mat.length; c++){
        sumC = sumC + mat[r][c];
      }
    }
```

Comment: how this one is gonna help the op? it looks u said the same thing?

Comment: While you can't do it now due to your reputation, please try in the future to keep these details in comments, and only answers in answers. :-) Welcome to SO!